# Cannot Install AutoItLibrary for Robot Framework on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, robotframework

I cannot install the autoitlibrary for robot framework on windows 10, when I try the commands below:

```
pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary
```

OR

```
pip install -U robotframework-autoitlibrary --no-cache-dir --pre
```

It begins the installation, but then it gives me the error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install -U robotframework-autoitlibrary --no-cache-dir --pre

Collecting robotframework-autoitlibrary
  Downloading robotframework-autoitlibrary-1.2.5.tar.gz (696 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 696 kB 6.8 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pywin32 in c:\users\guilherme\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from robotframework-autoitlibrary) (227)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pillow in c:\users\guilherme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from robotframework-autoitlibrary) (7.1.2)
```

Using legacy `setup.py` install for `robotframework-autoitlibrary`, since package **`wheel` is not installed**.

```
Installing collected packages: robotframework-autoitlibrary
    Running setup.py install for robotframework-autoitlibrary ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2:
     command: 'c:\users\guilherme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Guilherme\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cuz2ut7_\\robotframework-autoitlibrary\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Guilherme\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cuz2ut7_\\robotframework-autoitlibrary\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Guilherme\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-p7h0dafs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\guilherme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\robotframework-autoitlibrary'
         cwd: C:\Users\Guilherme\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cuz2ut7_\robotframework-autoitlibrary\
    Complete output (3 lines):
    Don't think we need to unregister the old one...
    %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\regsvr32.exe /S c:\users\guilherme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll
    AutoItLibrary requires win32com. See http://starship.python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/.
**----------------------------------------**
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2: 'c:\users\guilherme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Guilherme\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cuz2ut7_\\robotframework-autoitlibrary\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Guilherme\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cuz2ut7_\\robotframework-autoitlibrary\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Guilherme\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-p7h0dafs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\guilherme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\robotframework-autoitlibrary' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Details:

- I've already tried running the prompt as Admin as you can see above, but didn't work too.
- My python is the last version: `Python 3.8.3 (64bit)`
- I've already have installed robot framework: `Robot Framework 3.2.1 (Python 3.8.3 on win32)`

Can someone help me fix this?!

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me when I opened the command window as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem in my PC using `pip install --upgrade robotframework`. If this didn't work for you, try unistalling python and installing it again in Windows root filesystem: `C:\`.